# calling python in java doesn't work?

Tags: java, python, jython

I'm trying to execute the following code in java to call a python function with parameters but it's not working.

java code:

```
PythonInterpreter interpreter = new PythonInterpreter();
interpreter.exec("from function import somme");
PyObject someFunc = interpreter.eval("repr(somme(4,5))");
System.out.println(someFunc);
PyObject result = someFunc.__call__();
String realResult = (String) result.__tojava__(String.class);
System.out.println(realResult);
```

function.py:

```
def somme(x,y):
   return x+y
```

error:

```
 Exception in thread "main" Traceback (innermost last):
 File "<string>", line 1, in ?
 ImportError: no module named somme
```

Comment: thank you  @Ben Leitner  found the probleme

Answer (score 0):

the probleme was that the function.py file must be outside the src folder not inside it, works fine now.